# Entanglement question relativity

Tags: special-relativity, quantum-entanglement

Assume a particle's spin is measured along the vertical axis at time t=0 and position x=2.
An entangled partner particle is measured along the vertical axis at time t=0.5 and position x=0 (also along the vertical direction). In addition a measurement is performed at time t=1 and x=2 in the orthogonal direction. According to the standard observer the measurement of the entangled partner at (0.5,0) is performed before the measurement of the first particle at (1,2).
And yet according to a different observer the measurement at (1,2) is simultaneous with the event (0,0), so that (1,2) occurs before (0.5,0).
My question is: will the measurement at (0.5,0) be entangled with the measurement at (0,2) or the measurement at (1,2)?
The difference being whether the measurement at (0.5,0) has a 100% chance of being different from the one at (0,2) or only a 50% chance of being different?

Comment: Have you worked out the joint probability distribution for the three outcomes under each of the alternative  hypotheses?

Comment: I can only measure these spins once. I am not even sure I understand what you are talking about. It's not the individual measurements that are entangled. It's the systems that participate. There is, however, no quantum entanglement between macroscopic measurement systems. That's a basic premise of quantum mechanics.

Comment: The ordering of entanglement measurements has absolutely no observable effect on the statistical predictions.  Likewise: relativity and/or reference frame is not a factor.

Answer (score 2):

Measurements are not entangled. Particles are. Some event in the past has caused two particles to enter a state where their spins are antiparallel. The state is a superposition of 1 up 2 down and 1 down 2 up.

At some point in the future, the spins of both particles are measured. It will turn out that one is up and the other is down. It doesn't matter whether the measurements are simultaneous, or how far apart they are. They are always consistent.

This is one of the most counter intuitive things about quantum mechanics. Classical cause and effect does not work here. Before either measurement, the particles are in a superposition state. Afterward, they have individual spin states. Nothing travels from one particle to tell the other what state it is now in. It still works when the separation is space like.

Comment: Is this really all that counterintuitive in a relativistic setting? The measurements are relativistic scalars (we count the number of "ups" vs "downs" in our counters), but the measurements don't have to have a time-like separation, in which case an outside observer can not differentiate reliably about the order of events. Since all such observers have to agree about the scalar results, the order can not matter and there can be no causal connection. So in reality it's the other way around and it is relativity that forces the tensor product structure of Hilbert space. Am I missing something?

Comment: It sounds like you are talking about a meta cause-and-effect. Which law of physics causes which? Does relativity force there to be no causal connection or the other way around? I was talking about the measurement of one particle not being the cause of the state of the other particle in a classical sense. By this I mean the start of particle 1 being measured as spin up does not exert a force on particle 2 through a field that spreads at the speed of light. We see particle 2 come out with the right spin, but we don't see what caused the agreement.

Comment: Is my understanding correct that if particle 2 is measured along the horizontal direction and is found to be pointing leftwards or rightwards then particle 1 when measured along the vertical direction afterwards will be found to point upwards 50% and downwards 50% of the time?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: The laws of quantum mechanics are not really laws. Most of the structure of the theory is by design. Unitarity and linearity are not physical effects. They are mathematical requirements for an ensemble theory of statistically independent experiments. Energy is defined in exactly the same way as in classical mechanics because it is always being measured in a classical way. We have to assume that the actual event structure of the theory is the same as at the classical level, which means that one has to take special relativity seriously. These are not meta-theory but experimental facts.

Comment: If particle 2 is measured along the vertical direction at (2,0) and along the horizontal direction at time (2,1), then according to an observer who judges the event (0,0) to be simultaneous with the event (2,1), the order of events will be: measurement of particle 2 at t=0,x=0 in vertical direction, measurement of particle 2 at (2,1) in horizontal direction, and finally measurement of particle 1 at t=(0,0.5) in vertical direction. If the previous is correct then that means particle 1 will end up being found to be pointing upwards 50% of the time and pointing downwards 50% of the time?

Answer (score 0):

When you measure entangled particles they become disentangled and the measurement devices aren't entangled with one another:

https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0312068

In addition, the probabilities that the measurement results will be found to match don't depend on the order in which they are measured. It's difficult to see how the probabilities could be dependent on the order since the systems involved are described by local and Lorentz invariant equations of motion. The correlations arise when information about the results interacts and this process happens entirely as a result of local interactions:

https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9906007

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the measurement statistics will still show entanglement, even if in some frames of reference one measurement happens before the other.

One very interesting paper to look at is this one: https://www.nature.com/articles/nature15759 - especially look at figure 2.

In this experiment they go even more extreme than your example. They have a process that entangles two particles (nitrogen vacancy centres to be specific) by measuring the interference of photons radiated by those particles. This entangling measurement takes place at location C, where the particles themselves are at A and B respectively.

Measurements are carried out on the particles A and B, revealing that they are indeed entangled. However, very strangely, they don't need to wait for the entangling process at position C to have happened before doing the measurements at A and B! In some reference frames (for example one at rest with respect to the experiment) the particles at A and B are measured before the entangling operation has even happened, but post-selecting on cases where the entangling operation does successfully happen later is enough to find entanglement.

Entanglement is a confusing property, because a lot of the time it feels like a statistical correlation (for statistical correlation the above post-selection thing would be entirely unremarkable. Correlations are, by their very nature, nonlocal in space and time, because they correspond to relations between things in different places or at different times), but entanglement is also some actual physical property of the world (its a "thing"). Which is confusing because actual physical things are normally imagined to exist in particular locations or at particular times.

Comment: Photons don't interfere. Only electromagnetic waves, which are the expectation values of many photons interfere. To make a classical example for why "weird things" can happen with expectation values, consider dice. Each outcome can be a number between one and six. The average of many dice throws converges towards 3.5. There is no face on the dice that has a value of 3.5. Is this counterintuitive? Should this lead us to try to assign a value of 3.5 to individual dice throws? Obviously not. For the same reason it's not a good idea to assign a property like "interference" to individual photons.

Comment: @FlatterMann "Photons don't interfere. Only .... the expectation values of many photons interfere." - Could you provide a citation for this, or detail what you mean? The Hong–Ou–Mandel effect is a type of quantum interference involving two photons that is widely referred to as "two photon interference". (eg https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1361-6633/abcd7a). Related interference involving more photons are used in Linear Optical Quantum computing. The phrase "two-photon interference" or indeed "N-photon interference" is widespread in quantum optics literature, what is the objection?

Comment: A photon is the amount of energy that gets transferred irreversibly from the electromagnetic field to an external system that we usually call "detector". We can detect two photons at once, but it is not possible for one photon to "destructively" prevent the absorption of another. That classical waves can "cancel each other" is also a poor mental model, but it does not cause harm in that context. A better way to understand intensities in linear wave systems is as the result of a boundary value problem. It works in both cases, classical and quantum mechanical.

Comment: @FlatterMann I agree that one photon cannot cancel out the existence of another. However, I think this has lead you to make an overly strong statement. If two identical photons go into sperate input ports of a beam splitter we always get two photons at one output port and zero at the other (so 0-2 or 2-0, each with 50% probability). (The HOM effect). We never get 1-1. Photon interference can (and for the paper I linked in the answer to the OP does) lead to photons bunching in interesting ways. This is not cancelation of photons, but is nonetheless a photon interference effect.

Comment: A beam splitter is not an irreversible device. It does not absorb any of the energy in the field. There are no photons without that absorption process. The problem with QM is that it only tells us something concrete about irreversible processes that are happening at the system boundaries. It predicts relative frequencies (lots of photons in bright, few photons in dark areas) but it does not tell us how many photons there are where no absorption takes place. This can be seen the easiest in Copenhagen: the unitary evolution part makes no frequency predictions. Only the Born rule does.

Comment: @FlatterMann Sure, that is all fine. I feel I am still missing your point. I used the phrase "measuring the interference of photons" to describe a step in that paper's experiment, where they measured the HOM-interference of two photons. You think that this summary mis-characterises what happened in that experiment somehow, but I don't get how. For further context, to measure HOM interference one needs two detectors as well as the beam splitter. The HOM interference only impacts the intensity _variance_, it has no effect on its expectation value. HOM requires _exactly_ two photons.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151203/discussion-between-flattermann-and-dast).